# Where does the padding of TextBox come from?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textbox, padding

I have already set all `BorderThickness`, `Margin`, and `Padding` to `0,0,0,0`. Why is there still internal padding?

By the way, why is the text in `TextBox` of 24pt the same size of the text in `TextBlock` of 32pt?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This space is used for increasing touch area of a `Button`.

To remove it, in `Expression Blend` click `Template - Create From Copy`. Than go to xaml and find `Padding="10,5,10,3"` (something like that) and delete it.

Comment: Would you mind to tell me why there is still one or two pixels on the border compared to `TextBlock` without border?

Comment: Delete all margins you see here. For example, `Borders` thickness, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Margin="-10,-10,-10,-10" to remove the extra space reserved by WP

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.Current.Resources["PhoneTouchTargetOverhang"] instead of 10 in the solution above.